# React Hooks: How to useRef().current correctly and cleanly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've been using useRef in my function components as an alternative to class instance variables and I really like it. So typically it goes something like this:

First declare the variable, `scrollRef` for example:

```
const scrollRef = useRef()
```

Then, assign the value of some ref to `scrollRef.current`:

```
<ScrollView ref={ref => { scrollRef.current = ref }}>

// (Yeah, I'm doing mostly React Native)
```

Finally, use the ref:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => scrollRef.current.scrollToEnd()} />
```

This works fine. But when I have a lot of `useRef`s it seems like I have two problems:

1. `.current` is all over the place
2. there are some tricky cases and confusion when passing refs between components, when we're not immediately sure if we should read the value directly or read the `.current` key.

So I'm wondering if there is a better way.

I thought of declaring the variable with `let` instead of `const`, and then directly assign to `.current`:

```
let myRef = useRef().current
```

And then directly reading and mutating `myRef`

What are the drawbacks of this, are there cases where this would not work? Are there any better solutions to avoid using `.current` all over the place?

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to this and not even a react expert. But if you create a variable pointing to `current`, then write a new object to that variable, then your variable is no longer pointing to `ref.current`. The only thing you can do that preserves that link is modifying properties of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

There is a drawback to the `useRef().current` usage. Let's see below code(Using *React v18.1.0*):

```
import * as React from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [_, forceUpdate] = React.useReducer((x) => x + 1, 0);

  const r1 = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>();
  let r2 = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>().current;

  const r3 = React.useRef<string>();
  let r4 = React.useRef<string>().current;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('[useEffect] r1: ', r1);
    console.log('[useEffect] r2: ', r2);
    console.log('[useEffect] r3: ', r3);
    console.log('[useEffect] r4: ', r4);
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={r1}>r1 test</div>
      <div
        ref={(ref) => {
          r2 = ref;
        }}
      >
        r2 test
      </div>

      <button
        onClick={() => {
          r3.current = 'cool';
          r4 = 'cool';
          console.log('[onClick] r3: ', r3);
          console.log('[onClick] r4: ', r4);
          forceUpdate();
        }}
      >
        click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

After click the button, let's see the logs:

```bash
[onClick] r3: {current: "cool"}
[onClick] r4: cool
[useEffect] r1: {current: {…}}
[useEffect] r2: HTMLDivElement{attributes: {…}, innerHTML: "r2 test", nodeType: 1, tagName: "div"}
[useEffect] r3: {current: "cool"}
[useEffect] r4: undefined
```

I create two group refs for testing: `r1` and `r2`, `r3` and `r4`.

As you can see, the value of `r4` in `useEffect` is not what we expect. It's an `undefined` rather than a `'cool'` string. The value of `r3` is correct.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-ycbsje?file=App.tsx)